# How to reverse PayPal payment?

Tags: paypal, online-payment, payment

How to make a reverse on PayPal payment? I am a buyer of wonderful online goods and services, through sites like ebay. I have pay too much to my friend who sell me things and now I need to reverse the payment (he will sending me the extra).

How to do this? (Paypal NOT accept my fraud claim)…

Comment: Is this really your friend or is it possible you are being scammed? This sounds odd to me.

Comment: @Vicky https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/89513/selling-items-online-is-this-buyer-trying-to-scam-me

Comment: The recipient of a paypal payment has the option to issue a partial refund. So, if it's your friend, they can refund you the amount of the extra payment. Your question is a bit strange, you say you paid a friend, but you also filed a fraud claim against this friend.

Comment: Why the need to reverse, if your friend is going to transfer back the difference anyway? Sounds a bit weird to me.

Comment: **You are being scammed, or you yourself are involved in the scam.**

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon but he is a buyer of wonderful online goods?

Comment: Is this an instance of someone trying to use SE to learn how to scam someone?

Comment: So, you've asked your friend to send you the difference between what you paid and what you were supposed to pay, and you're **also** reversing the transaction, so they're out the agreed-upon amount? That sounds a lot like fraud & a very common type of money-forwarding scam.

Answer (score 4):

Your friend should be doing **a "partial refund"** *inside of the PayPal system*.  That is a special feature in the seller controls.  If he can't figure it out, he can do a full refund and then you can make the correct payment this time.

The above advice assumes he is either a friend or a businessman who is happy to work with you (the *vast* majority are, business isn't about chiseling every possible dime i.e. ["never give the money back"](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_Acquisition): it's about cultivating relationships and building social reputation).

Now if you are fighting each other, then you need to go to either the PayPal refund system (which won't work if money was sent as a "gift") or, you need to go to your credit card company and do a *chargeback*.  American Express is aggressively consumer-friendly and will almost certainly side with you.  Visa and Mastercard are not quite as much, again you will likely win but it's not as sure.

A chargeback doesn't wipe out the debt, it just cancels the payment method.  You still owe whatever you owe.